# moderncv - why so many files?

Tags: formatting, moderncv, document-classes

As a very hands-on type of person, I said to myself why not learn `LaTex` trying to build something out of it, in order to learn all the intricacies of `LaTex`.

So I'm creating my cv, using `LaTex` and `ModernCv`.

While doing my cv, I cannot help myself notice that `LaTex` seems to be heavy, using 4 files

- `moderncv.cls`
- `moderncvcolorblue.sty`
- `moderncvcompatibility.sty`
- `moderncvstylecasual.sty`

Questions are the following:

- Why did the moderncv splitted into 4 files? Would it not have been easier to put it , into 2 files as an example
- I read something about `classes`and `packages`but my understanding is a bit fuzzy on that one.

Any helps to shed some lights on it are more than welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Those are files the end user should not even care about. Users want different styles, different colors, different ... which makes documents more complex and harder to understand. If people would be satisfied with what standard LaTeX provides, we would have no questions at all, wouldn't need to read complex documentation to fix small parts in documents and all our documents would look exactly the same. So, in short: Diversity means Complexity.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B Keeping my question for a bit and if no one else is answering, I'll delete it. Cheers.

Comment: The question should imho be deleted, since A) a part of it is a fuzzy question, which can not be answered clearly and B) the other part can be googled easily.

Comment: But don't delete questions too soon, like the last one, you did. If there is no exact (!) match in TeX.SX other users might help your question.

Comment: I like the impetus for creating a CV, but I would go even further: don't use any class and create your own. In the process you will likely learn about: how tables work, how lists work, how bibliographical references may be created, how to modify sectional headings, how to make hyperlinks, how to construct headers and/or footers, and probably much more about different commands and environments. `moderncv` teaches you how to follow a template (which is useful), but a CV could introduce you to many of the fundamentals of the LaTeX world. And after doing it in LaTeX, try to make one in plain TeX!

Comment: @jon's is the 'labor of love' approach

Comment: Hi @jon, many thanks for your answer. I did not say anything due to lack of time but I managed to have my cv sorted. Not a difficult one for a first timer and I'm quite proud of what I've done. I feel like copying writing all these great authors. But I guess that we all started to somewhere, to go deeeper and be more knowledgeable. Cheers

Comment: Hi @SeanAllred, the word `work` has root in the word `tripallium`, which means something akin to `torture` yet thinking about what Camus said, you need to love the process, the `go-deeper` but I guess I'll save my breath for another comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, class `moderncv` changed a lot and that is the reason, why it was divided into several files.

The main files are

- `moderncv.cls`,
- `moderncvbodyX.sty`,
- `moderncvheaderX.sty` and
- `moderncvfootX.sty`.

They define the cv and the letter depending of the used style and colour.  `X` can be a roman number between `i` and `v`, depending if it is body, header or foot.

The style and the colour are predefined in the files

- `moderncvcolorY.sty` and
- `moderncvstyleZ.sty`

`Y` stands for an predefined colour, `Z` for an predefined style.

Because there were several changes, there are some old commands defined in earlier versions.  File `moderncvcompatibility.sty` makes sure, that the old commands can be used with newer versions ...

The advantage is that one can better design different layouts for cv and letters, the disadvantage is that it is harder to change the layout for an user.

If you want to learn more about writing classes and packages I suggest you read `clsguide.pdf`.  Just type `texdoc clsguide` into your terminal/console to open this document.